# libbullet error installing drcsim-2.2

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have openrave installed, which uses libbullet-2.81

When I try to install drcsim-2.2 I get the following errors

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libbullet_2.81-1ppa1~precise_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried again:

```
Groovy$sudo apt-get install drcsim
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
drcsim is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gazebo : Depends: libbullet but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
Groovy$sudo apt-get -f install 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libbullet
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libbullet
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/906 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,289 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
(Reading database ... 340839 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libbullet (from .../libbullet_2.81-1ppa1~precise_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libbullet_2.81-1ppa1~precise_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/libBulletSoftBody.so', which is also in package libbullet2.80 2.80.2-ubuntu1~precise1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libbullet_2.81-1ppa1~precise_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1766/libbullet-error-installing-drcsim-2.2/) by [dcconner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47/dcconner/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 298 on 2013-03-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) on 2013-03-13**:
Gazebo pulls in libbullet-2.81 from the OSRF repository. Unfortunately it conflicts with the existing bullet version you have installed  which looks like it's libbullet-2.80. You'll probably have to uninstall that before installing gazebo.

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47/dcconner/) on 2013-03-13**:
I neglected to include the part where sudo apt-get remove libbullet was giving me an error after this.  Removing libbullet before trying the -f install on another machine avoided this issue, so drcsim-2.2 is working on that machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This should be consider as a bug. I have filed a [ticket](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/release-tools/issue/13/make-all-libbullet-osrf-packages-conflict).

As iche033 comments, a workaround is to uninstall system libbullet and install OSRF provided libbullet. What is going to happen with openrave, if it was installed from packages, will depend upon the package dependencies. If it depends on **exactly** libbullet-2.80, we should look at it carefully because probably the fix is not trivial. Feel free to start a ticket if this is the case.

Otherwise, installing it on top of OSRF libbullet should work.
Thanks for reporting.

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2013-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0